# Starting off an IIR with plain averages to accelerate slow rise time

Tags: filters, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response

A 1-term IIR can easily be started off with the first data point, instead of 0.
For data that's all > 0,
this ought to be better than starting off with `y = 0` :

```
def update( x, t, a=0.1 ):  # data x (scalar or vector), t 0 1 2 ...
    global y  # or self.
    if t == 0:
        y = x
    else:
        y += a * (x - y)  # fraction `a` of the way towards x
    return y
```

It's also easy to start off with plain averages (FIR) for the first few data points,
then switch to IIR:

```
def update( x, t, a=0.1, naverage=10 ):
    if t <= naverage:
        a_t = 1. / (t + 1)  # start off with plain averages, 1 1/2 1/3 ...
    else:
        a_t = a       # then IIR
    y += a_t * (x - y)
```

The goal here is to accelerate the slow rise time of `y` when `a` is small.
Is this reasonable ?
Are there less ad-hoc ways of doing this ?

---

Added 28 Nov, a plot showing the difference:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are omitting the initial condition of the filter:

$$y(t)=\alpha x(t-1)+(1-\alpha)y(t-1)$$

which is

$$y(0)=x(0)=x_0$$

which is implemented by correcting this line before the cycle:

```
if t == 1:
    y=a*x;
```

You dont need to switch anything. Only provide that value and an initial evaluation with that index, and you will not have a slow rise problem.

2016-11-22
The following image shows the result of putting the proper IC to the filter. In red there is the standard "zero" IC, while the green shows the correct IC. The $x(t)$ is a step periodic signal. Note that the IC is perfectly matched with the expected result.

[image]

2016-11-23

Another depict for a biased Laplacian Noise, and different parameters for a linear filter, with IC settled as indicated. Note that regardless of the IC setting, all the signals are around the bias, which is the correct result. 
[image]

Comment: The first code snippet starts at the first $x$ (1-origin, so your $x(0)$). The question is, can one do better, with time-varying $a_t$ interpolating FIR .. IIR ? Need a plot of 3 cases: start 0, start $x(0)$, start say $x(0..5)$ .

Comment: Note that the initial condition is not a vector index, but a initial value taken by the filter expression. You have to add an additional line previous the `for` cycle. There are no need for interpolating, the filter *starts* at the correct value, with no rise at all.

Comment: Your filter starts at `a * x`, mine at `x`: try `x = 100, a = 0.05` .

Comment: With any value of `a` and with a constant input `x`=$x_0$ the initial condition `y=a*x` will let the filter static at the value $x_0$, without any ripple or raises.

Comment: Could you plot 5 + that ? The question says "For data that's all > 0 ..."  My code is under https://gist.github.com/denis-bz

Comment: Now, i am fairly unclear of what are you asking. The green line on your plot starts in the first sample. Which seems to be ok. What do you need exactly?. Remember that a linear filter will always behave the same way against the outlayers (such as the point at t=2). Can you draw by hand on your plot how do you want your filter to look like?

Comment: Can you paste your final data into the question or in here for reproduce the filter?

Comment: Does anyone else find the question unclear ? If so I'll delete it -- this is getting out of hand. Repeat: $y_0 = x_0$, not $a * x_0$; or, $y_1 = (x_0 + x_1) / 2$; or ... The data: `np.random.seed(1);  10 + np.random.laplace(20)`

Comment: No problem Denis... the idea is you get your concerns solved.... You should not delete it if you still have them. Formulating it in order to get to the core question is part of the answer.